# I want to extract data between html tag from web site in android.?

Tags: php, android

How to extract data between span tag from web site in android? I am trying with php and android but not getting result can you please help me for that problem.?
please Find below the code from where we want to extract data which is highlighted .

```
Número<br /></span><span class="linha">**3943**</span></td><td valign="top" height="30" width="25%"><span class="TextoFundoBrancoNegrito">
Série<br /></span><span class="linha">**0**</span></td><td valign="top" height="30" width="25%"><span class="TextoFundoBrancoNegrito">
Data de emissão<br /></span><span class="linha">**26/08/2013**</span></td></tr></table><table align="center" width="98%"><tr><td class="TituloAreaRestrita">
```

I want to store data  "3943" , "0" , "26/08/2013" in `String`.

Comment: you use jsoup for parsing html tags

Answer (score 1):

You can extract data from HTML using [Regular Expressions](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html).

Use the following code to extract data between your span tags:

`String value = regexMatch(HTML, "<span class=\"linha\">(.+?)</span>");`

Here is the  function:

```
public static String regexMatch(String source, String compilePattern) {
    // Compile regex pattern
    Pattern regexPattern = pattern.compile(compilePattern);

    // Create a matcher against input
    Matcher regexMatcher = regexPattern.matcher(source);

    // Find first match
    if (regexMatcher.find()) {
        // Return first group
        return RegexMatcher.group(1);
    }

    // Return empty string if no match
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are after a string paser or substring methods... this is fairly standard for any developer. What code are you using currently?

Basically you load the whole html data into a single string and then strip it down to only the conent you need. This can be done with split methods that will split a string into an array or other means... this subject has already been covered multiple times...

Comment: i am Just searching solution for that problem now I am not using any solution.

Comment: Google java substrings and string split methods

Comment: As answered by Elad, using something like Reg Expressions will do the same thing. Basically what you are wanting to do is split your string down to segments you need to use.

In logic terms, your are trying to do..

FIND/LOOP every "<span" tag, Then find next > character.. This will give you the starting point for your value.

Then you find the next "</span>" which will give you a ending point for your value.

Afterwards you would use a trim to remove any blank spaces/padding. 

So you run a substring loop for every "<span", find the next ">" and start there, until you find "</span>" and done.

Comment: RegEx is recommended, but not for all users.